# Why do this code have a compile error in switch

Tags: java

I don't understand. that why have a error.
I want to know why this code have a error.

```
static void test(Object obj) {
        switch (obj) {
            case Character c:
                if (c.charValue() == 7) {
                    System.out.print("Ding ");
                }
                if (c.charValue() == 9) {
                    System.out.print("Tab ");
                }
                System.out.println("character");
            case Integer i:                 // Compile-time error
                System.out.println("An integer " + i);
            default:
                System.out.println("Neither character nor integer");
        }
    }
```

if I remove "case String..". it does not have a error

```
static void test(Object obj) {
        switch (obj) {
            case Integer i:                 // Compile-time error
                System.out.println("An integer " + i);
            default:
                System.out.println("Neither character nor integer");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where exactly was this ```case String...``` part?  You mean the ```case character c``` part, right?  What is the compiler error?

Comment: Always post the full error message with your question. Always.

Comment: Falling through from one case to the next doesn't make sense once patters are used -- what would the value of `i` be? Why do you want to execute the `Integer` case every time the `Character` case matches?

Comment: To avoid more down-votes, edit your Question to include exact error message.

Answer (score 0):

### tl;dr

In Java 21 and later:

```java
    switch ( obj )
    {
        case Character c -> System.out.println ( "Is Character: " + c );
        case Integer i -> System.out.println ( "Is Integer: " + i );
        default -> System.out.println ( "Some other class: " + obj.getClass ( ).getCanonicalName ( ) );
    }
```

In earlier Java, add `break` statements.

### `break` halts fall-through

I am guessing the error you mention (but neglected to document) was "Illegal fall-through to a pattern". Your `switch` is trying to continue on through all the cases. But given the different class types of each case, that makes no sense. Hence that error (or so I am guessing).

The immediate fix is to add `break;` statements to stop the case-fall-through.

```java
static void test ( Object obj )
{
    switch ( obj )
    {
        case Character c:
            if ( c.charValue ( ) == 7 )
            {
                System.out.print ( "Ding " );
            }
            if ( c.charValue ( ) == 9 )
            {
                System.out.print ( "Tab " );
            }
            System.out.println ( "character" );
            break;  // <----------
        case Integer i:  
            System.out.println ( "An integer " + i );
            break;  // <----------
        default:
            System.out.println ( "Neither character nor integer" );
    }
}
```

Try it.

```java
App.test ( 'x' );
App.test ( 42 );
App.test ( "whatever" );
```

Results:

```
character
An integer 42
Neither character nor integer
```

### Simplify your code

Your IDE might suggest some improvements to your code.

One is replacing the unnecessary explicit unboxing of `.charValue`. Java will do that for you, auto-boxing.

```java
        if ( c == 7 )
        {
            System.out.print ( "Ding " );
        }
        if ( c == 9 )
        {
            System.out.print ( "Tab " );
        }
```

And really, this code does not help your demonstration. So let's stick to simple `println`.

```java
static void test ( Object obj )
{
    switch ( obj )
    {
        case Character c:
            System.out.println ( "Is Character: " + c );
            break;
        case Integer i:         
            System.out.println ( "Is Integer: " + i );
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println ( "Some other class: " + obj.getClass ( ).getCanonicalName ( ) );
    }
}
```

When run:

```
Is Character: x
Is Integer: 42
Some other class: java.lang.String
```

### Java 21: Pattern Matching for `switch`

Java 21 brings more pattern matching. See [*JEP 441: Pattern Matching for switch*](https://openjdk.org/jeps/441).

We can use the arrow operator `->` to execute code for that case. This syntax eliminates case-fall-through, so no `break` needed.

```java
static void test ( Object obj )
{
    switch ( obj )
    {
        case Character c -> System.out.println ( "Is Character: " + c );
        case Integer i -> System.out.println ( "Is Integer: " + i );
        default -> System.out.println ( "Some other class: " + obj.getClass ( ).getCanonicalName ( ) );
    }
}
```

Simpler code, same results.

```
Is Character: x
Is Integer: 42
Some other class: java.lang.String
```

For more info on pattern matching, see some good talks on YouTube etc., and read the Java JEPs.

---

By the way… avoid using `char`/`Character`. That type has been essentially broken since Java 2, and legacy since Java 5. As a 16-bit value, `char` is physically incapable of representing most characters. Instead, make a habit of using Unicode [code point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point) integer numbers to work with individual characters.